# Groß- oder Kleinschreibung bei mehreren eingeschobenen Sätzen zwischen Gedankenstrichen

Tags: capitalization

Schreibt man *nein* im folgenden Beispiel groß oder klein?

> Johann hielt – überrascht? nein, erfreut! – inne.
>
> Johann hielt – überrascht? Nein, erfreut! – inne.

---

Alternatives Beispiel für Menschen, die meinen, "Überrascht?" sei kein Satz:

> Johann hielt – war er überrascht? nein, er war erfreut! – inne.
>
> Johann hielt – war er überrascht? Nein, er war erfreut! – inne.

---

Für die Schlauberger, die meinen, nach einem Einschub stünde kein Satzzeichen (Quelle: [Duden](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/gedankenstrich)):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Wenn man mit der Syntax wie hier kreativ umgeht, dann findet man auch keine strikten Regeln für die Details, sondern hat eine gewisse Freheit.

Ich finde beides ok. Für mich gehört das alles letztlich zu dem umgebenden Satz. Die eingeschobenen Teile sind ja syntaktisch keine Sätze, sondern letztlich nur zwei alternative Adverbien, deshalb würde ich persönlich das alles klein schreiben. Aber ich verstehe auch, wenn man stattdessen die Regel priorisiert, dass man nach einem Satzzeichen normalerweise groß weiterschreibt.

Edit: auch im hinzugefügten Beispiel mit den ganzen Sätzen würde ich klein schreiben, um zu vermeiden, dass der Leser noch mehr als nötig aus dem Lesefluss geworfen wird, weil er den falschen Eindruck bekommt, der umgebende Satz sei nach "hielt" zu Ende. In der letzten Variante kommt der Teil "- inne." wohl für jeden Leser überraschend. Das ganze zweite Beispiel gehört natürlich sowieso stilpolizeilich verboten.

Answer (score 1):

Ich plädiere für (nochmals leicht abgewandeltes Beispiel)

```
Johann hielt - war er überrascht? Nein: Er war erfreut! - inne.
```

Die Großschreibung von "Nein" nach dem Fragezeichen (und von "Er" nach dem Doppelpunkt, weil "Er war erfreut!" ein ganzer Satz ist) hat nichts mit dem Einschub zu tun, dessen Beginn und Anfang ja auch weit von diesen Stellen entfernt liegen. Dagegen wird "war" (und erst recht "inne") klein geschrieben, wie es sich halt bei einem Einschub gehört.

**Aber:** Ich würde eine solche Konstruktion lieber vermeiden, es sei denn, der gesamte Einschub ist - auch wenn es sich sogar um mehrere "ganze" Sätze handelt! - sehr kurz. Ansonsten besteht leider die Gefahr, dass der Leser Schwierigkeiten beim "Parsen" hat.

```
Johann hielt - war er überrascht?
```

könnte für sich alleine Sinn ergeben und endet mit einem wohlverdienten Satzende. Wenn man dann weiterliest, (man stelle sich nur vor, dass ausgerechnet an dieser Stelle eine Seite umgeblättert werden muss)

```
Nein: Er war erfreut - inne.
```

stößt einem der Satzbau erst mit dem allerletzten Wort "inne" auf, und man muss sozusagen von vorne anfangen - ein Verbrechen am Leser :)

Answer (score 0):

Das Fragezeichen ist ein Satzzeichen und beendet als solches einen Satz. Ich habe ein etwas über 200 Seiten starkes Büchlein aus der Duden-Reihe mit dem Titel *»Komma, Punkt und andere Satzzeichen«* (aus dem Jahr 2002), das gerade mal 5 1/2 Seiten dem Fragezeichen widmet, und dort finde ich nichts, was man als Ausnahme von dieser Satz-Ende-Funktion interpretieren könnte.

Die Wortfolge *»Johann hielt überrascht«* ist aber kein Satz, egal ob mit oder ohne Gedankenstrich. Insbesondere fehlt da noch ein Teil des trennbaren Verbs *innehalten.* (Das Wort *»inne«*, dass am Ende der anderen Satzes steht, gibt es als alleinstehendes Wort nicht. Es kommt nur als Vorsilbe eines trennbaren Verbs vor.) Aus diesem Grund dürfte nach *»überrascht«* also eigentlich gar kein Fragezeichen stehen, und Gedanken darüber, wie das darauffolgende Wort zu schreiben sei, erübrigen sich dann.

Die Tatsache, dass da aber ein Fragezeichen steht, katapultiert uns unweigerlich aus dem Geltungsbereich jeglicher Grammatik hinaus. Wenn man aber bereits fröhlich die Regeln biegt, darf man sich von genau diesem Regelwerk auch keine Hilfe bei Fragestellungen wie der vorliegenden erhoffen.

Eine mögliche Lösung wäre diese Schreibweise:

> Johann hielt überrascht – nein, erfreut – inne.

Comment: Es handelt sich hier zwar um einen Einschub, aber nicht um eingeschobene Sätze. Das Setzen von Satzzeichen innerhalb des Einschubs ist eher ungebräuchlich und wird auch von den meisten Grammatiken, - wie Hubert richtig schreibt - daher nicht berücksichtigt. Ich würde wahrscheinlich die Großschreibung nach dem Fragezeichen bevorzugen - ich sehe nicht, dass an der Kleinschreibung irgendwas "besser" wäre. Im Duden habe ich folgendes Beispiel gefunden, wo nach  einem Fragenzeichen, das einen unvollständigen Satz beendet, ebenfalls groß weitergeschrieben wird: *Wie denn? Wo denn? Was denn?*

Comment: @user52445: Ich weiß schon, was ein Einschub ist. Aber *»Sie erinnern sich noch?«* ist eben ein ganzer Satz, der mit einem Großbuchstaben beginnt, ein Verb und ein Subjekt enthält, und daher mit einem Fragezeichen abgeschlossen werden kann. Aber auf *»überrascht«* trifft nichts davon zu. Nachdem du dieses Wort kleingeschrieben hast, kann es nicht der Anfang eines Satzes sein. Daher muss der Beginn des Satzes davor liegen, und da kommt eben nur *»Johann«* infrage. Aber wie man es auch dreht und wendet: Die deutsche Standardgrammatik erlaubt hinter *»überrascht«* kein Fragezeichen.

Comment: @user52445: Aber du willst doch nicht ernsthaft behaupten, dass das Wort *»überrascht«* bereits ein Satz ist, oder doch?

Comment: Selbstverständlich. Was ist eine Äußerung wie "Komm!" denn sonst? Duden: "Ein Satz ist eine Einheit, die aus einem finiten Verb und allen vom Verb verlangten Satzgliedern besteht." In diesem Fall verlangt das finite Verb keine weiteren Satzglieder. Es handelt sich also laut Duden um einen vollständigen Satz. Siehe auch die zahlreichen übereinstimmenden Definitionen unter https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satz_(Grammatik). Keine davon schließt Ein-Wort-Sätze aus!

Answer (score -1):

Die Regel, dass bei wörtlicher Rede oder (wie im vorliegenden Fall) der Wiedergabe von Gedanken nach einem Ausrufe- oder Fragezeichen ausnahmslos großzuschreiben ist, scheint es nicht zu geben.
Soll die Pause zwischen dem fraglichen Wort und dem Vorgängerwort besonders kurz sein, würde ich daher kleinschreiben.

> Nicht ziehen! drücken!

Und bei Standardpausen eben groß.

> Ende! Das war's.

Die Kleinschreibung signalisiert dem Leser höhere Geschwindigkeit.

Bei deinem Beispiel scheint mir die Großschreibung angemessen.